# How to handle a segmentation fault occurred in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, client-server, pyodbc

I have written a piece of code that checks in a system if there is a new entry in the database or not if a new entry is found it will fetch the data and client will try to send it to the server ... but if data is continuously found in every execution of threading.timer cycle it will try to send it to the server...

Now issue is if the server is unreachable then it will print that server is not alive etc. if this cycle goes for few minutes the script just crash and it shows Segmentation Fault ... i want to handle this exception and wanted to process something if Segmentation fault occurs

working environment:
linux
python3
sql-server

**EDIT**

This is what shows after script gets crashed...

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0xb3dff460 (most recent call first):

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 294 in wait File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 553 in wait File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1184 in run File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920 in _bootstrap_inner File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 888 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0xb33ff460 (most recent call first):
  File "abc.py", line 343 in send_to_server
  File "abc.py", line 244 in sql_connect1
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1186 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 888 in _bootstrap

Thread 0xb45ff460 (most recent call first):
  File "abc.py", line 408 in send_to_server
  File "abc.py", line 244 in sql_connect1
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1186 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 888 in _bootstrap

Thread 0xb4fff460 (most recent call first):
  File "abc.py", line 343 in send_to_server
  File "abc.py", line 244 in sql_connect1
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1186 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 888 in _bootstrap

Thread 0xb6f39300 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1076 in _wait_for_tstate_lock
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1060 in join
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 1294 in _shutdown
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Segmentation faults are often thrown from within the ODBC driver code, rather than from the pyodbc code itself. Which ODBC driver are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson

`code`
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver
Driver = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
`code`

Comment: @GordThompson 

Pyodbc version is :
---
Name: pyodbc
Version: 4.0.26
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

i have searched more and found that 4.0 version have this issue of Segmentation fault ? please also confirm this and suggest what to do now to fix this issue..

Answer (score 0):

well i didn't know a segmentation fault was even possible, a segmentation fault mean that somwhere you go too far in the memory to a place that is not mapped.
you should note the line where it is said the problem originally happened and check the lines.

Comment: This is possible because [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) is written in python and C++. So it must be c++ code that segfault.

Comment: @AldricLiottier i didnt create Segmentation Fault .. it existed in this Universe

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, but :

- you are using python3.4, but we don't know the exact version, so maybe upgrading to the last version of 3.4 (or better, upgrading to 3.6 or 3.7) could help.
- we also don't know what version of pyodbc you are using. Maybe this bug has been resolved. But there are [several seg fault reported in github](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=segfault)
- we don't see you're code. Maybe you make use of the driver incorrectly (can't see why but...)

Comment: Do you know exception handling for Segmentation fault ? if so then kindly prove me some examples.

Comment: Segmentation fault usually means that Python crashed/a module caused Python to crash. You cant catch this with an exception handler. Work around the buggy code or upgrade the dependency/Python.